# How to get div table data to show in right order in mobile view with bootstrap3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, html-table

I'm using **Bootstrap3**, and I'm using the following code which shows properly on my desktop; however, when I view this in mobile it shows in the wrong text grouping.

I would like it to show like this in mobile view:

- Header 1
- Detailed description text for Header 1
- Header 2
- Detailed description text for Header 2

However, it shows like this when I view this in mobile view:

- Header 1
- Header 2
- Detailed description text for Header 1
- Detailed description text for Header 2

This is the **div** code that I set up:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 clearfix text-left">
        <p>Header 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 clearfix text-left">
        <p>Header 2</p>
    </div>              
</div>      
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
        Detailed description text for Header 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
        Detailed description text for Header 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you're using bootstrap. Put all 4 columns in a single row and then use the push / pull helper classes to re-order the columns at mobile view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want it to look like, but just putting everything in columns would work. Like this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
      <p>Header 1</p>
      <p>Detailed description text for Header 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 text-left">
      <p>Header 2</p>
      <p> Detailed description text for Header 2</p>
    </div>              
</div>
```

play with it here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZOpKx